# Dynamically change column widths in ExtJS 6 dashboards

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

Is there a way to change the column widths in an [`Ext.dashboard.Dashboard`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.dashboard.Dashboard) after it has been rendered? It is created with a config value of:

```
columnWidths: [
    0.35,
    0.40,
    0.25
]
```

I want to dynamically change it to:

```
columnWidths: [
    0.5,
    0.25,
    0.25
]
```

Changing the `columnWidths` property directly or with `setConfig` does not update the dashboard.  It doesn't appear to have a method for "refresh" or anything else that obviously serves the same purpose. The individual dashboard-columns have a `setWidth` function but that doesn't seem to do anything either.

Comment: In which case you want to change column width? Do you want to change when screen resize?

Comment: My  use case is actually a menu with presets like "set all columns to an equal width", so the user can quickly equalize or align all the columns and/or widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the API that managed this automatically but you can manually update the `columnWidth` values of each child component in the dashboard and then call `updateLayout`:

```js
function setColumnWidths(dashboard, columnWidths){
    var i = 0;
    dashboard.items.each(function(item){
        if(item instanceof Ext.resizer.Splitter)
            return; // ignore
        item.columnWidth = columnWidths[i++] || 1;
    });
    dashboard.updateLayout();
}
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14cs)